# make raw file path to uri at android

Tags: android

i want to a uri:

```
Uri uri =Uri.parse("android.resource://com.haier.Uhome9110/raw/"+"alarm_buzzer.ogg");
File file = new File(uri.toString());
                if(file.exists()){
                    Log.i("uri ","exists ");
                }else{
                    Log.i("uri ","not exists ");
                }
```

it give me not exists, i changed

```
 File file = new File(uri.getPath());
```

it also give me not exists.
i donot know my mistake,i think the uri is mistake,how to put the raw file path to the uri.i need the uri,and my file need put at the raw.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
Uri uri =Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.yourfilename);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: "android.resource://com.haier.Uhome9110/"+R.raw.alarm_buzzer not useful

Comment: Uri uri =Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.alarm_buzzer); also not useful